# Why doesn't the following function stop for an input 1?

Tags: c

I'd like your help with understanding why this function does not stop when I enter any other number than 1.

```
int main(void) {

double sum,v;

while (scanf("%lf",&v)==1) {
    printf("\t%.2f\n", sum += v);

}
```

It looks like it's suppose to stop whenever the input would be different from 1. I believe that it is has to do with the condition, maybe it checks something before what I think it does.

Comment: When you aren't sure how a `C` library function works there is documentation all over the internet. [Here is an example](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html). Note that your `sum` variable isn't initialized so it may contain a random garbage value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `scanf` returns the number of items matched and filled, not the actual value it read.

> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of
>   successfully matched and assigned input items; this number can be zero
>   in the event of an early matching failure. If the input ends before
>   the first matching failure or conversion, EOF shall be returned.

So in your code `scanf` will always return `1` for a successful read. You should be testing `v` instead (but not with `==`).

Comment: What do you by "number of items matched and filled"? The number of items she got as input?

Comment: You might expand on the reasoning for your comment on the ==.  Odds are he may not be aware of the issue.

Comment: @EvilTeach You're right but I think it's outside the scope of the answer.

Comment: then perhaps it should not be mentioned at all.

Comment: @EvilTeach I just noticed your username is **Evil** teach :-))

Answer (score 0):

scanf on success returns the number of items successfully read. Therefore you need additionally check if `v == 1`.